# K-means on linearly projected features

Tags: clustering, k-means

I am looking for references on K-Means applied to linearly projected features instead of to the original features, in the sense that both K-Means and the projection matrix are learned at the same time.

I am aware of deep learning methods that can do the same thing even for highly non-linear projections, but I have the feeling that for the linear case, this problem has been well studied in classical statistics or machine learning, with nice theoretical properties.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: A frequent method is PCA + clustering, it is not done at the same time though.

Comment: @user2974951 Thanks, but that's not exactly what I was looking for.